# the correct way to write alert function and msg

Tags: reactjs, angular, alert

where can I write the alert function in this case, i have form with onSubmit to send email.

```
  <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} >
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or why it's tagged w/ both Angular and React. The `onSubmit` function can do whatever it wants, including opening an alert.

Comment: right but whats the correct way to adding the alert on onSubmit function

Comment: By modifying `sendEmail`? By using a function that does the alert and the `sendEmail`, either a separate function or an anonymous arrow function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved in the following way:

```js
const sendEmail = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   window.alert(“Alert text”)
}
```

```js
<form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} />
```

Don't forget to create an input.

Comment: Yep - `window.alert` or just `alert('Are you sure?')` or rather `confirm('Are you sure?')` are all correct.